# Как обновить запись с дублирующейся уникальной ячейкой?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Такая проблема. При создании записи в `knigafull` добавляется запись в таблице `knigi` с некоторыми пустыми значениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда читатель "берет" книгу, в таблице `knigi` обновляются записи (в `id_chitatelya` подставляется его айди, а в `id_knigi` та книга, которую он взял)

UPDATE `knigi` SET `status` = 'на руках' , `id_chitatelya` = '$chitatel',`vremya_vzyatiya` = '$time', `data_vzyatiya` = '$data' WHERE `id` = '25'

Беда в том, что при попытке "взять" вторую книгу выходит ошибка с дублированием записи по айди читателя. Как это можно поправить?

Duplicate entry * for key *

Comment: у вас каждая книга в единственном экземпляре представлена,что вы прям вместе с книгами храните информацию о том, у кого она на руках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверняка в таблице у вас `id_chitatelya` является уникальным полем (UNIQUE). Уберите уникальность.